# display data dynamically from the JSON data using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I display JSON data (Parent-Child-Grandchild) in three separate div elements using jQuery or Javascript?

[image: ![enter image description here]

According to my current code this is not dynamic only shows JSON data in separate divs but in the right div all children are displayed (it also shows great-grandchild)

If the user clicks on a `grandchild` label (if it has a child) then the `grandchild` label should appears in the middle div and their child (great-grandchild) should be shown in the right div.

I want to make all labels dynamic so that when a user clicks any label then the label shows in the middle div and its children shows in the right div.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "parent": 0,
    "name": "Parent"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parent": 1,
    "name": "Child"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent": 1,
    "name": "Child"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parent": 2,
    "name": "GrandChild"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "parent": 2,
    "name": "GrandChild"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "parent": 3,
    "name": "GrandChild"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "parent": 3,
    "name": "GrandChild"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "parent": 5,
    "name": "Great-GrandChild"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "parent": 5,
    "name": "Great-GrandChild"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "parent": 6,
    "name": "Great-GrandChild"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "parent": 7,
    "name": "Great-GrandChild"
  }
]

let getById = (id, data) => {
  let r = data.find(x => x.id === id);
  if (r == undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  return r;
}

let add = (row, data) => {
  let class_name;
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    if (row.id == "1")
      class_name = "left_side";
    else {
      let parent = getById(row.id, data);
      if (parent.parent == "1") {
        class_name = "middle_side";
      } else {
        class_name = "right_side";
        if (getById(parent.parent, data) === false)
          return false;
      }

    }
    $("." + class_name).append(`<span id="${row.id}" class="label">${row.name}</span>`);
  }
}

$.each(data, (index, value) => {
  if (add(value, data) === false) {
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w-100 d-flex">
  <div class="eq_width align-self-center left_side">
    <span id="1" class="label">Parent</span>
  </div>
  <div class="vl"></div>
  <div class="eq_width align-self-center middle_side">
    <span id="2" class="label">Child</span>
    <span id="3" class="label">Child</span>
  </div>
  <div class="vl"></div>
  <div class="eq_width align-self-center right_side">
    <span id="4" class="label">GrandChild</span>
    <span id="5" class="label">GrandChild</span>
    <span id="6" class="label">GrandChild</span>
    <span id="7" class="label">GrandChild</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your issue? What did you try?

Comment: You've set the requirements. What's the question? If you have an issue implementing this, then please add your code to the question so we can help you debug it

Comment: I update my code please check @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Thank you for editing. Do you have any control over the structure of the `data` array? This can be made *much* simpler if you change it to be a hierarchical data instead of flat

Comment: okey...I can change it to hierarchical @RoryMcCrossan . But i want to change data onclick event. How can I do?

Comment: Thank you @LuudJacobs . But i want to change data onclick event. How can I do?